# Hibernate DetachedCriteria in FROM clause

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

I have 2 tables:

```
    orders: id
    items: id, orderId, total, flag
```

I would like to make following query using Hibernate Criteria (DetachedCriteria):

```
    SELECT
        o.id,
        SUM(i1.total),
        SUM(i2.total)
    FROM
        orders o
            LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                    i.orderId as orderId,
                    SUM(i.total) as total
                FROM
                    items i
               WHERE
                    i.flag = 0
               GROUP BY
                    orderId
           ) AS i1
           ON i1.orderId = o.id
            LEFT JOIN
           (
               SELECT
                i.orderId as orderId,
                  SUM(i.total) as total
                FROM
                   items i
               WHERE
                   i.flag = 1
               GROUP BY
                    orderId
            ) AS i2
            ON i2.orderId = o.id
    GROUP BY
        o.id
```

I know how to use `DetachedCriteri`a to create subquery in `WHERE` clause, but as you can see, I need to do a subquery in `FROM` clause. If it is not possible, maybe there is a way to write it in `SELECT` clause (inside `SUM()`), because this query could be rewritten to such form.

I really need to use Criteria API even if I have to pass native SQL to the query.

I didn't show you classes or mapping, but as you can see, this is a very simple example.

Comment: You didn't show us classes or mapping, but the Criteria API is expressed in terms of the object model, not SQL.

Comment: Yes, I already said that. This example is so simple, that I don't think classes or mapping are needed here, because maybe my problem can't be resolved using Criteria API.

Comment: Did you tried using projections for this? Adding mapping and classes always helps to check a tip before posting.

Comment: @prostynick: my point is that how can we advice you on how to query the object model when we don't know what it looks like? Multiple outer joins, aggregations and subqueries do not make for easy reverse engineering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my problem. I had to make a POJO and mapping:

```
<class name="OrderTotal"
    entity-name="OrderTotalForFlag0">
    <subselect>
        SELECT
            i.orderId AS id,
            SUM(i.total) AS total
        FROM
            items i
        WHERE
            i.flag = 0
        GROUP BY
            id
    </subselect>
    <id name="id" type="int" />
    <property name="total" type="int" />
</class>
```

And of course for flag 1 it will be similar. This could be also done by declaring views in database and creating a mappings to that views. In this example I was using the same POJO class, but different entity-name.

Then I made a property in class Order and mapping:

```
<one-to-one name="orderTotalForFlag0" entity-name="OrderTotalForFlag0" />
<one-to-one name="orderTotalForFlag1" entity-name="OrderTotalForFlag1" />
```

Of course laziness could be set.

I'm pretty sure now, that this could be also done in different way - by making subquery in `SELECT` clause - using the `formula` attribute/element in mapping for properties, but this would work slower than subquery in `FROM` clause.

And of course all of that was in documentation to Hibernate ;)